# Jira-Python : How can we fetch the commentor name by passing object?

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I'm trying fetch the data of commentor name in the recently updated issue. I'm saving the updated issues in a list, when I'm passing the list in the query it gives me : `AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'comment'`, even though there is comment present on the issue.

Can anyone please help?

Below is the code

```
def issue_tested(project_name, updated_from, updated_to):
    print project_name, updated_from, updated_to
    total_update=[]
    total_update = jira.search_issues('project = %s AND updated >= %s and updated <= %s' % (project_name, updated_from, updated_to))
    total_updated_length = len(total_update)

print total_update
print total_updated_length
print total_update[2]
issue = jira.issue(total_update[2])
print issue
print issue.fields.comment.comments[0].author.name
```

I'm getting the issue , but it is not getting passed in the print `issue.fields.comment.comments[0].author.name`. However when I directly assign the issue like : i`ssue = jira.issue('Issue_name')`, it gives me the author name. But while passing it as an object shows Attribute error.

PS: I don't want to use Script-Runner as it as paid now, can you please give me any solution within python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

The reason why you get this error is that by default [`search`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/search-search) method returns issues with navigable fields:

> By default, only navigable (*navigable) fields are returned in this
>   search resource. Note: the default is different in the get-issue
>   resource -- the default there all fields (*all).

When you execute `issue` method:

```
issue = jira.issue(total_update[2])
```

you pass `issue` object, not string. Inside that there is a condition:

```
if type(id) == Issue:
    return id
```

i.e. it just returns the original method from `search` execution, which was missing the *comment* field.

#### Solution

1. You can ask `search` method to include *comment* field to the result:

   ```
   total_update = jira.search_issues(jql_str='project = %s AND updated >= %s and updated <= %s' % (project_name, updated_from, updated_to), fields='comment')
   ```
2. You can query an issue by it's key:

   issue = jira.issue(total_update[2].key)

Method #1 is preferable, unless you need to get comments for some specific issue.